# java - Spring @Value annotation returns null

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to take advantage of `@Value` annotation and auto-populate my string-variable from the properties file, but with no luck. Values are not being set and are `null`.

Here is my configuration:

**SendMessageController.java**

```
@RestController
public class SendMessageController {

    @Value("${client.keystore.type}")
    private static String keystoreType;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendMessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<SendMessageResponse> sendMessage(@Validated @RequestBody SendMessageRequest messageRequest) {
    .......
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
client.keystore.type=JKS
```

**rest-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.controllers" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

When I run my application and try to access `keystoreType` variable it is always `null`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please make sure the import statement for `@Value` annotation is `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;`?

Comment: Spring doesn't process `static` anything. Why is your field `static`?

Comment: okay, after making the variable non-static, everything works fine. thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring can not inject `@Value` to a static field directly.

you can either add inject the value through an annotated setter like this:

```
private static String keystoreType;

@Value("${client.keystore.type}")
public void setKeystoreType(String keystoreType) {
    SendMessageController.keystoreType = keystoreType;
}
```

Or Change :

```
    @Value("${client.keystore.type}")
    private static String keystoreType;
```

to :

```
@Value("${client.keystore.type}")
private String keystoreType;
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, this solved the problem

Comment: sure! waiting for the timeout :)

Comment: @RafikBELDI This thing is not working for me. I am calling the static method from other class , which has the static var .

Answer (score 1):

For the ones still facing the issue after all the preceding suggestions, make sure you are not accessing that variable before the bean has been constructed as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62323587/5615357).